# Rails 4 application in netbeans

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, netbeans

I have created a new rails application in NetBeans with rails 4.0.2 version and ruby 2. When I run the application it throws a error saying script file missing .
The application contains Scripts file , NetBeans is not allow me to edit the folder name from Scripts to script . If I am able to edit it then the issue is fixed.

Comment: hey did you found a solution?